# Remove variable name from legend in ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survminer

Is there a concise way to remove the variable name in the legend of plots created by `ggsurvplot`?
Example:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

set.seed(123)
df=data.frame(gender=c(rep("male", 10), rep("female", 10)), value=c(rnorm(10,mean = 2), rnorm(10,mean = 3)))
fit = surv_fit(Surv(value) ~ gender, data = df)
p = ggsurvplot(fit, data = df,  surv.median.line = "none")
```

[image]

What I want is to remove the word 'gender' from the legend as in the following plot. I can achieve this by manually setting the legend labels:

```
p = ggsurvplot(fit, data = df,  surv.median.line = "none", legend.labs = c("male", "female"))
```

But is there a better way?

EDIT: I accidentally swapped male and female when I manually assigned the gender (2. plot), which shows how dangerous this method is.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hack the `strata` with `gsub`.

```
names(fit$strata) <- gsub("gender=", "", names(fit$strata))
ggsurvplot(fit, data=df, surv.median.line="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine, thanks a lot! Even though I was hoping for an option included by the makers of the package.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the mistake of swapping the legend labels, use this option in the ggsurvplot function instead: `legend.labs = levels(df$gender)`

Comment: This is an ideal solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the attribute of `strata`

```
attr(fit$strata,'names') <- c('female', 'male')
```

and then make the plot

```
p = ggsurvplot(fit, surv.median.line = "none")
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. But I don't want to type 'male', 'female' manually.